# Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_Token_ELLIPSIS' not found

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

[image]

Trying to generate code coverage report excuting the command

**phpunit --coverage-html report**.

Test execution is successful but failed to generate the report and throwing the below error:

`Class 'PHP_Token_ELLIPSIS' not found in C:\xamppNew\php\pear\PHP\Token\Stream.php:205`

Comment: Do you have the coverage module installed? Try: `composer require --dev phpunit/php-code-coverage` first.

Comment: Hi noam, coverage module is there ```C:\xamppNew\php\pear\PHP\CodeCoverage```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire output, when you run the tests and the coverage? Preferably not using a photo.

Comment: Hi Noam, the issue got resolved. Under the whitelist directory tag in phpunit.xml file I have mentioned the name of test file which was not required. After removing the file name and keeping only the directory it worked. Anyway Thanks Noam.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer, so that other people have a hint when they see this question in the future.

Comment: Ok sure. I will add.

Answer (score 1):

Neither your screenshot nor your written questions contains information about the versions of PHP you are using. But we can do some detective work: Your error message contains `PHPUnit_TextUI_Command`. PHPUnit has not been using class names like that for your year. Your path contains `pear`, suggesting you installed PHPUnit using PEAR (I wonder how). PEAR-based installation has not been used for years.

It appears that you are using an outdated version of PHPUnit, with outdated dependencies of PHPUnit. With syntax in the test(ed) code that is not supported by one of the dependencies of PHPUnit, namely php-token-stream.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to **Sebastian Bergmann** for looking into the question and giving best possible input from your end, even though you found some required information missing to answer this question.
Actually I didn't install PHPUnit using PEAR. But I installed XAMPP and in that case PHP and PHPUnit comes along with it.
Current version of PHP and PHPUnit running in my system are PHP 7.2.27 and PHPUnit 3.7.21 respectively and you guessed it right that PHPunit is the outdated one.

But still I was able to resolve the issue as I mentioned in my conversation with Noam.
From the phpunit.xml file I have removed the name of the file for which I wanted to generate the PHPUnit testing coverage report.Now only keeping the path of the file to be tested and it worked.

**Earlier Approach:**
[image]

**Current Working Approach:**
[image]